# Was I too harsh?

Tags: support

Just wondering if I was too harsh in my comment on this answer to my question.

> Because that's what I was curious about, silly-headed person. Who are you to come here and tell me what kind of inquiry I am allowed or not allowed to have? You're making philosophical arguments here, not physics ones. Go start your own question if you want to say something different.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/346589/1483

The answerer wants my question to be a different one and doesn't like the question as asked. His answer reveals this bias. I'm ok with leaving his (wrong) answer, but why is he trying to convince me the selected answer is wrong? The site agrees that the selected answer is a correct answer to the given, valid, question.

Note that I have updated my comment as follows to avoid potentially being rude or abusive, or being flagged as such:

> Why? Because that's what I was curious about. Why do you come here and tell me what kind of inquiry I am allowed or not allowed to have? You're making philosophical arguments here, not physics ones. If you want to say something different, how about asking your own question instead of mis-answering mine?

Comment: I mean, I wouldn't have gone as far as to call him _silly_; but I don't quite understand his comment.  He seems to not want to acknowledge the premise of the question.  I'm not really sure if his naming of other scientists in the comment was relevant.

Comment: It'd be very helpful to quote the comment here

Comment: Honestly, doesn't seem to bad to me. I think Gypsy's answer is spot-on - no need to possibly make trouble.

Comment: Honestly, it was probably a bit undeserved. The answerer needs to work on getting their point across, but I interpret it as them saying that your question discusses a moot issue (which it does) and that in any practical situation, variances in parameters are enough to not only drown out the difference, but to actually remove the difference entirely. A valid point, but worded in an unpleasant way. A response along the lines of "I'm just asking because I'm curious what the math says" is more appropriate. After that, there's nothing more you'd have to respond with

Answer (score 4):

Too harsh? Not particularly so. It may have been well earned.

Still, it is a tad personal as well, and probably should be *corrected* such that it's less likely to be interpreted as a personal attack and earns you a flag of "rude or abusive."

No point making trouble for yourself when there is no need.